# grails - forcing select list values to be saved as date to oracle db

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I'm working on an app to track sessions for a conference and want to allow the user to select dates from a drop down but have the dates stored as a date in the oracle database.  I've tried using the date picker but want to limit the options.  Here is the code I am currently using.

```
<g:select name="sessionDate" from="${session_MasterInstance.constraints.sessionDate.inList}" value="${formatDate(format:'mm/dd/yyyy', date:session_MasterInstance?.sessionDate)}" noSelection="['null': '']" />
```

The values I want to display do display correctly but when I try to create a new record I receive `Propery sessionDate must be a valid Date`

I have `sessionDate(nullable:true, inList:["11/21/2011","11/22/2011"])` in my domain class and sessionDate of Date format in my Oracle DB.

Please advise.  I'm new to grails so this is probably very simple.

Answer (score 0):

It might be this issue: [GRAILS-6604](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6604) (there's a workaround there for pre-1.3.6).

What Grails version are you using?

I'm in doubt about `inList` that contains `String`s for values. If this constraint produces errors, I'd try  `inList: [new Date(2011, 11, 21), new Date(2011, 11, 22)]`.

Comment: Grails 1.3.7 Thank you for the suggestion but that did not work.  I still receive "Property sessionDate must be a valid Date"

Comment: Just to recap I have sessionDate(nullable:true, inList:[new Date(2011,11,21), new Date(2011,11,22)]) and Date   sessionDate set in my domain class and working from my Edit.gsp I have 
<g:select name="sessionDate" from="${session_MasterInstance.constraints.sessionDate.inList}" value="${formatDate(format:'dd-MM-yyyy',session_MasterInstance?.sessionDate)}" valueMessagePrefix="session_Master.sessionDate" noSelection="['': '']" />